# AWS Java API for Spot automated bidding maximum price and allocation strategy

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I just realized that AWS has new Spot instance launch wizard and adding some new options like Maximum Price and Allocation Strategy options.

[image: Spot instance launch wizard]

I'm developing an application that uses Java API, mainly RequestSpotInstancesRequest to launch spot request.
However, I can't find any documents or any reference API (including aws cli docs too) that I could use to set those mentioned options. I'm using AWS SDK version 1.11.77. Any suggestion or information how to use these options through API is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same API.  This one is called [spot fleet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html).

[`aws request-spot-fleet ...`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-fleet.html)

[API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RequestSpotFleet.html)

Note also that a fleet can be a "fleet" of just one, of course.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for. I have another question about the spot price though. From docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html here. It seems like I have to supply the spot price anyway, at least for the global spot price, but not via the wizard. Do I need to supply the market price manually to simulate the 'automated bidding' option?